# Queue in c# how does it work? (types allowed, initialization and fields)

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, queue

I'm writing a piece of software in C# and I can't figure out queues. Here is simplified situation: I have a server and a communication interface already in place. Server spews out data continuously at a certain rate and I want to put that into a queue-type buffer (the order in which data comes in and out is very important as it is going to be decoded and then sent to a database over a different connection). The issue is: When I try to create a class to hold my buffer (as well as other data) I define it as

```
public class BufferingClass
{    
    public Queue<string[]> ServerDataBuffer;

    // rest of the code
}
```

But I'm getting error that `Queue does not exist in current context`

I can define it as

```
public class BufferingClass
{
    public Queue ServerDataBuffor

    // rest of the code
}
```

Surprisingly enough assigining different types of objects to queue defined like that (like `INT` `STRING` `BOOL` or arrays of other classes) are okay as far as compilator is concerned (I was not bold enough to run such a program)

So here is my question. What exacly is queue? I'm not asking about trival thing like it is a FIFO colection. I am simply surprised that it is something that is not as strongly typed as everything else in this langage and even though it looks like a list and smells like a list, defining it in a similar way raises red flags by the compiler.

Also How is Producer-Consumer problem handled? I know that from the Producer side of things if I keep pumping data into my `Queue` then OS will simply double its capacity until it runs out of memory and more space can't be allocated. But what signals are sent to code when dequeue is called while buffer is empty? or do I have to take care of that `manually`? especially when one thread is adding to the queue and other is consuming from it.

Comment: It's not clear which type you're talking about. There's `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` and `System.Collections.Queue`. Those are different types; you should almost certainly be using the generic type though. My guess is that in the first case you're missing an import (and `Public` should be `public` - or better, `private`...)

Comment: My appologies. Yes I made a typo here with the Public. It is fixed now. I was refering more to the <> there and not to the capitalisation of the word "Public"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Queue<string[]> ServerDataBuffer;
```

This isn't valid C# line, this must be a `public`, not `Public`.

I think that this is a simple typo. And, as @JonSkeet mentioned, there are two different classes, [one of them is a generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), and [second is not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx). Moreover, there is a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), which is oriented for multithreading environment and is generic too. Inner algorythms are complex enough for not to try explain them here. You can find the sources for them.

Example for concurrent queue ([from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)):

```
// Construct a ConcurrentQueue.
ConcurrentQueue<int> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

// Populate the queue. 
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) cq.Enqueue(i);

// Peek at the first element. 
int result;
if (!cq.TryPeek(out result))
{
   Console.WriteLine("CQ: TryPeek failed when it should have succeeded");
}
else if (result != 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("CQ: Expected TryPeek result of 0, got {0}", result);
}

int outerSum = 0;
// An action to consume the ConcurrentQueue.
Action action = () =>
{                
   int localSum = 0;
   int localValue;
   while (cq.TryDequeue(out localValue)) localSum += localValue;
   Interlocked.Add(ref outerSum, localSum);
};

// Start 4 concurrent consuming actions.
Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action);
Console.WriteLine("outerSum = {0}, should be 49995000", outerSum);
```

Another implementation for the concurrent FIFO queue is [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414.aspx) class from [TPL Dataflow library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx).
If you interested in `Producer/Consumer` implementation with limited size, see the [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) class implementing [`IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147.aspx)

As you can see, there are a lot of generic solution for your problem. Read about the options and choose them as you need.